# Arithmetic Mean

Tags: algorithm, vhdl

I need to design a circuit which accepts n numbers at the input (infinite input) and calculates the average of these numbers as the output. The numbers for the input can only be of values <0,15>.
I need to implement this circuit in VHDL but I cannot find the proper algorithm since I need it to design the logical schema. I understand that I will definitely need a 4bit adder and some registers to store the values. I tried to understand the problem using moving average principle but it just did not work at all.

Comment: So you're not using moving average? And there are infinite number of input? That means as the number of input increase, the mean is going to be less and less sensitive to new data. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input `n+1`, with value `x`, the average will be equal to `(average*n+x)/(n+1)` --> ... = `average + (next - average)/(n+1)`.
From this observation a simple algorithm can be derived:

1. Initialize all registers to 0
2. Get the next input and store it in temp register
3. Increase count register by 1
4. Subtract previous average from temp register
5. Divide the temp register by count
6. Add temp to average
7. Go to step 2

Answer (score 1):

Lets see, you'd need as input ports: reset, input[3:0], clock; outputs: average[3:0] and internal registers accumulator[a:0] and count[c:0].
I can't remember the syntax of my VHDL and Verilog just now but...

whenever you get an input you need to add it to the accumulator, increment the count by 1, then set the average to be the accumulator divided by the count.
On reset set the accumulator and count to zero.
If you know the maximum number of values for incrementing is countmax then the accumulator needs to be big enough to hole countmax*15 and count has to have enough bits to hold countmax.
This will also give you a size for the divider.
If countmax is unknown then you need to add an overflow output and set it when the accumulator overflows and un-set it on reset.

Hope that helps.